# Remove duplicates if columns values are same after exchange in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill'], 'matched_name':['mary','john','jeff','lisa','jose'], 'ratio':[78, 78, 22, 19, 45]})
print(df)
    name   matched_name  ratio
0   john      mary        78
1   mary      john        78
2  peter      jeff        22
3   jeff      lisa        19
4   bill      jose        45
```

I want to remove duplicated rows based on condition: if columns `name` and `matched` after exchange their cell place are same values and `ratio` also same then those rows are considered as duplicated rows.

Under above rules, `row 0` and `row 1` are duplicates, so I will keep only `row 0`. How could I do it use Pandas? Thanks.

This is expected result:

```
    name matched  ratio
0   john    mary     78
1  peter    jeff     22
2   jeff    lisa     19
3   bill    jose     45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.sort` for sorting values per rows, add column `ratio` and test duplicates by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), last filter by inverse mask by `~` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['name', 'matched_name']], axis=1), index=df.index)
       .assign(ratio=df['ratio'])
       .duplicated())

df = df[~m]
print (df)
    name matched_name  ratio
0   john         mary     78
2  peter         jeff     22
3   jeff         lisa     19
4   bill         jose     45
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.astype(str).values,axis=1)).drop_duplicates().index
df=df.loc[df.index.isin(m)].reset_index()
print(df)

   index   name matched_name  ratio
0      0   john         mary     78
1      2  peter         jeff     22
2      3   jeff         lisa     19
3      4   bill         jose     45
```